# Ruby path and applet with archive

Tags: java, ruby, jar, path, applet

I'm trying to use a java applet (client side) with ruby. The  declaration I use in a local html file does not work when I run it using localhost as the server. I see a routing request for the .class file (there isn't one just a jar) and a relative path does not get correct path. I put the jar in /public/lib. The browser shows localhost/publication/new as the URL.

Working declaration in a local html file:

```
  <object id="applet" height=100 width=100 ><br/>
  <param name="code" value="Ciphermancer.Client.ClientApplet.class"/><br/>
  <param name="archive" value="public/lib/clientEncryption.jar" /><br/>
  <p>fails</p><br/>
  <object><br/>
```

Declaration in xxx.html.erb file:

```
  <object id="applet" height=100 width=500 type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2">
  <param name="code" value="Ciphermancer.Client.ClientApplet.class"/>
  <param name="archive" value="clientEncryption.jar" />
  <p>fails</p>
  </object>
```

I see the following routing error on the server:
Started GET "/publications/Ciphermancer/Client/ClientApplet/class.class" for 127.0.0.1...

Changing to drop the ".class" in the code parameter and adding the relative path of "../public/lib" results in:
Started GET "/public/lib/Ciphermancer/Client/ClientApplet.class" for 127.0.0.1...
and the error from the java plugin manager is: class not found "...public.lib.Ciphermancer.Client.ClientApplet"

Adding 'src="../public/lib/clientEncryption.jar"' to the  tag results in the proper request to the server, "/public/lib/clientEncryption.jar" but that still results in a routing error.In any case I don't know if the jar would be used after being downloaded.The server shows 4 attempts to get the jar followed by 2 attempts to get the class file.

It seems to come down to 2 issues:

1. A route declaration to allow the jar download
2. A route declaration to avoid the routing error on the class file (need not found)

Running jruby 1.7.3 on macbook, java JRE 1.7.0

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of looking and trying things I found a solution, use  as above but start the archive path with a '/' (an absolute path):

```
 <object id="applet" height=100 width=500 type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.4.2">
<param name="code" value="Ciphermancer.Client.ClientApplet.class"/>
<param name="archive" value="/clientEncryption.jar" />
<p>fails</p>
</object>
```

The jar is placed in /public. It turned out to be simple after blind alleys of finding out how link_to_image worked based on format and where image resources were placed.

There have been a few threads on this issue:
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/189022
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/154767
and others